# How to run google business API using account id and location id

Tags: magento2.4.1, google-api

I have an account id and location id, how to run the following script in Magento 2

```
<?php 
$accountId = 'your_account_id';
$locationId = 'your_location_id';
$url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/'.$accountId.'/locations/'.$locationId.'/reviews';    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
/*If data is in xml format
$output = simplexml_load_string($output); */
$allData = json_decode(json_encode($output), TRUE); // You will get all the data
?>
```

I want to share these review details into my custom phtml file, what is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To achive this into your website, you need to do like this one.

1. Create custom Block for the phtml file.
2. Do the code into block file by passing the proper parameter required to access the information.
3. Now call assign that block type of your phtml file and then call block function into your phtml file.

Comment: Can you pls explain in details, so that i can write the module

Comment: I am getting values from google business client api, how to include it into the custom module block, can you pls help me with that.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/336365/57334 can u pls help me, thanks.

Comment: I am using Google client api library in in xampp/htdocs/reviewapi/test.php, this is return my reviews. How to convert this thing into my module.

Comment: I am new this concept, there is minimum of resources only available, can you pls help me on this, really appreciated.

Comment: Hi Dhiren Vasoya, can i get help, thanks

Comment: How you added custom phtml file into the system? can you share the xml file code what you have done.

Comment: Bro, i just did the google client api thing only, i am getting response, Link : https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git, using this how to create custom module

Comment: Bro, I need help to create custom module for google business review api, finally, i want to display my reviews on my page, can you pls guide me on this, really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi Dhiren Vasoya, can i get some ref for including google review api into custom module and call insode the phtml page.

Comment: In block how to call API thing, in google client library this is my main file to get reviews, https://codeshare.io/a3Owd4